What's the translation of "a scenic overlook" in French?
What's the translation of "a scenic overlook" in French?
Google Translate suggests "un belvédère panoramique", but Larousse defines a belvédère as:

Pavillon ou terrasse qui couronne et domine soit un édifice, soit un tertre dans un parc, et d'où la vue s'étend au loin. (Le Belvédère du Vatican est un petit palais du xve s. qui abrite des antiques tels que l'Apollon et le Torse dits « du Belvédère ».)

whereas an overlook isn't necessarily a pavillon ou terrasse.

Ca marche quand même.

@Frank thanks, good to know!

You're right, an overlook can just be a natural landmark and belvédère most often implies  a man made construction. But as often said on FL context is everything and you are not giving any. Overlook, as a noun, is usually translated by point de vue and  point de vue panoramique would be a better translation, at least to my mind.

"Scenic overlook" on DeepL.

@None and Frank thanks, you're welcome to post it as answer.

scenic overlook is American highway parlance and maybe Brit too. //A scenic viewpoint – also called an observation point, viewpoint, viewing point, vista point,[1] lookout,[1] scenic overlook,[1] etc. – is an elevated location where people can view scenery (often with binoculars) and photograph it. Scenic viewpoints may be created alongside scenic routes or mountain roads, often as simple turnouts or lay-bys where motorists can pull over onto pavement, gravel, or grass on the right-of-way. Wikipedia.

The definition given in the Larousse is a partial definition, and the TLFi provides that part also (see below).

(TLFi) ARCHIT. Petit pavillon ou terrasse au sommet d'un édifice, d'une maison, ou sur une éminence et d'où la vue s'étend au loin

However, The TLFi also mentions an extension (P. ext., par extension) of this definition (same link).

− P. ext. Plate-forme naturelle située sur un lieu élevé, qui constitue un point de vue remarquable pour découvrir un paysage :

De-là il nous conduisait sur un promontoire très-élevé et d'un accès difficile, couvert de beaux cèdres, d'où l'on découvroit presque toute l'étendue de cette vallée; c'étoit ce qu'il appeloit en souriant son belvédère. Crèvecœur, Voyage dans la Haute Pensylvanie,t. 2, 1801, p. 41.
De Vézelay, belvédère naturel, on voit à une lieue vers l'est le paysage, tout bourguignon jusque-là, changer d'aspect. Le Morvan s'annonce comme une croupe à peine accentuée en saillie, mais qui contraste par son uniformité, sa tonalité sombre avec le pays calcaire. Vidal de La Blache, Tabl. de la géogr. de la France, 1908, p. 112.


The constructions associated with  overlooks are often so insignificant if not non-existent that the images that are used to talk about them are in fact the views that they afford over the surroundings.
                                                     
(Probably nothing has been constructed on that site.)
https://www.savoie-mont-blanc.com/visite-culture/sites-naturels/belvedere/
                     
https://www.savoie-mont-blanc.com/fiches/belvedere-du-col-de-lepine-5621394/HIVER/

(Here again, the word "belvédère" does not refer to the construction, which is not much to speak of, but instead to the elevated place from where you can see far away down below.)
https://www.savoie-mont-blanc.com/fiches/belvedere-du-faucigny-108666/
It follows that the term "scenic1 overlook" does correspond simply to "belvédère", which is still a modern term, and it can be seen in the sources that figure in this answer that "panoramique" is not used (likewise for numerous other sources that I cannot mention). "Belvédère panoramique" is a term that you might refer to as neither fish nor fowl: it is probably the result of the ambiguity that the two definitions must cause. It is found in the references, but not as often as the plain term (https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=belv%C3%A9d%C3%A8re+panoramique). I do not know which one is more appropriate, but there is a certitude: they both mean the exact same thing.
Note: 1. The term "scenic overlook" itself appears to be pleonastic:
(SOED) overlook A (high) place affording a view of the scene below. Chiefly US.
2. The conjugation endings "oit" in the TLFi examples are ancient forms that have been replaced by "ait" in modern French.
Addition due to user Lambie's comment
(scenic overlook is not pleonastic because you could have an overlook that looks over something very ugly.)
"Scenic overlook" could appear to be pleonastic, but in fact is not, as "overlook" is a more general term than "belvédère"; that is, one should not be induced to think from the SOED definition or some such like definition, that the scene below is necessarily scenic (see a definition of "scenic" in a dictionary). However, in many cases it is not necessary to add "scenic" in order for an overlook to be scenic (sometimes it just goes without saying (Blue Bluff Overlook)).
1 This adjective has been added in consequence of the addition made above.

C'est charmant le terme belvédère. Mais c'est canadien plus que français de France.  An overlook, c'est un arrêt panoramique sur une route de montagne, p. ex.

@Lambie Charmant, peut-être, en particulier, si on a une certaine affection pour les termes à consonance italienne, mais plutôt canadien, non, je ne crois pas. // « Arrêt panoramique » va bien pour les belvédères sur les routes de montagne (un terme dont le sens va presque de soi). // Merriam-Webster n'est pas si restrictif (« a place from which one may look down on a scene below »), et leur définition correspond à celle du SOED..

@Kamala-1FTW Peut-être s'agit-il d'une simple coquille et que la phrase attendue était C'est italien plus que français de France ;-)

@LPH. Et où penses-tu qu'on trouve lesdits overlook? They are all on mountains or hills. They always have a parking space, which is why they are un arrêt in French. //Je doute fort qu'autrefois on arretait les chevaux pour regarder les panoramas sur les routes. https://thebanffblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/Peyto-Lake-Lookout-1024x683.jpg Et pour le Canada: Arrêt panoramique à la pointe Merry du lac Memphrémagog; https://ici.radio-canada.ca/television/bonsbaisersfrance/concours/tous_a_bord_orford_express/index.shtml

Yes, overlooks can be ugly (a.k.a. bruttovedere), an unfortunate overlook from LPH.

Some comments explains that scenic overlook is used on road signs to tell the drivers that they can park there and have a nice panoramic view to a natural landscape.
US road signs tend to be very talkative while European ones follow the Vienna convention on Road Signs and Signal that prefer using symbols and pictograms when possible. One of the obvious advantage of this system is once you know the signs, you can drive with greater confidence and safety in countries you ignore the language.
Without this convention, you would risk to miss the scenic overviews if you don't understand what is written.
The road sign used to signal scenic overviews is generally named in French point de vue remarquable or point de vue exceptionnel and it looks like this:

The sign can be rotated by 180° to tell the view point is toward the left side.
In addition to the pictogram, the sign can also read some text, either a generic one like Point de vue, Belvedere or Panorama, or also indicate the name of the site or some other piece of information like table d'orientation, table de lecture du paysage, etc.
You might even find this very pleonastic sign:


Very pleonastic indeed, stating 3 times the same info. Thanks!

A "belvédère" can refer to any type of structure made to admire the scenery from. It ranges from a gazebo (from which I guess you are supposed to admire the surrounding garden) to some kind of plate that pictures the scenery with indications.
For a more general way to talk about a place from which the view from (independent of whether it is built or not) you can use "point de vue".

gazebos don't overlook scenes "en hauteur. Only gardens etc.

@Lambie What has your comment to do with Anne Aunyme reply? She already refers to 'gazebo' in a garden context and belvedere doesn't strictly imply any significant hauteur. You know, like your "underground perchoir" :-)

L'acception du mot belvédère en français est bien plus large que le terme scenic overview en anglais. Et oui, cela peut traduire le terme. Tout comme point de vue. Et "scenic overview" en anglais est utilisé sur les panneaux routiers. Les scenic overview se trouvent toujours en hauteur sur les routes/autoroutes. Sinon ils ne seraient pas des "over + view".  Voir Wikipedia et aussi les images des panneaux routiers en anglais.
